# how to get pdf context into html?

Tags: javascript, html, pdf

for several days now I'm learning html, CSS and now javascript. What I need is a way to get the informations of an pdf document into my html webpage.

I tried several things now and couldnt find the correct answer or informations I need. So here come an use case:

1. get an .pdf document into a folder
2. get the information of all .pdf documents of the target folder (with the exact same formatting)
3. convert those information into html context
4. get this html context to show on the webpage (images and text)

1 is trivial, I can just drag and drop my documents

2 I'm thinking about something like an array, which then calls the folder to get data into it.

For this I found:

```
'use strict';
function getFiles(dir) {
  fileList = [];

  var files = fs.readdirSync(dir);
  for (var i in files) {
    if (!files.hasOwnProperty(i)) continue;
    var name = dir + '/' + files[i];
    if (!fs.statSync(name).isDirectory()) {
        fileList.push(name);
    }
  }
  return fileList;
}
console.log(getFiles('pathtodirectory'));
```

Here I'm always getting a reference error, no matter what the path, well I can use only a local path on my pc for now. I'm not 100% sure what everything does, but I think I got it good so far. This function just gets me a list of the documents to work with.

3 That's even more tricky for me now, but I think if I get the data to work with, I may be able to work something out.

4 I think I can do it with a little research

I am happy for any tips or solutions, as I said I'm quite new to all of this :)

regards,

Pascal

Answer (score 0):

```
'use strict';
function getFiles(dir) {
  fileList = []; // <- This becomes a global variable
```

Should be:

```
'use strict';
function getFiles(dir) {
  var fileList = []; // <- Now it's local to this scope
```

Because creating implicit global variables are not allowed in strict mode.

Also the `getDirSync` return an array, so you should treat it as such:

```
function getFiles(dir) {
  fileList = [];

  var files = fs.readdirSync(dir);
  for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
    var name = dir + '/' + files[i];
    if (!fs.statSync(name).isDirectory()) {
        fileList.push(name);
    }
  }
  return fileList;
}
```

Or with `.reduce`:

```
function getFiles(dir) {
  return fs.readdirSync(dir).reduce(function(arr, file) {
    var name = dir + '/' + file;
    if (!fs.statSync(name).isDirectory()) {
        arr.push(name);
    }
    return arr;
  }, []);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I feel blind for not seeing this, however, Now I'm getting this mistake in the next line "var files = fs.readdirSync(dir);" I'm not really sure what this does. I got this from http://resolvethis.com/how-to-get-all-files-in-a-folder-in-javascript/. Hope this helps :)

Comment: @pgalle Updaded the answer, hope it helps

Comment: fs is not defined, how do i define it? The error appears as soons as "fs" is called and I feel like I don't understand the file system yes. I just know some of what is written here: https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html and maybe this one: https://github.com/substack/brfs/issues/36 , however as I said, I don't understand it entirely :/

Comment: Add this to the top of your file: `var fs = require('fs');`

Comment: "require is not defined" is there package missing or something? I got this for now: fs = require('fs');
function getFiles(dir) {
    return fs.readdirSync(dir).reduce(function (arr, file) {
        var name = dir + '/' + file;
        if (!fs.statSync(name).isDirectory()) {
            arr.push(name);
        }
        return arr;
    }, []);
}

console.log(getFiles('C:/Users/Myrmod/Desktop/papa/Webseite/Presseberichte'));

Comment: @pgalle You need to run the code with node js, not a browser